# btc RBF insufficient fee, rejecting replacement

Tags: replace-by-fee

I try to replace this transaction 13bc8f787f7c972702b6d14b8c0b36335aac5d0027800e2de277910a5eff86fb by higher fee, when broadcast return err: `broadcast error, -26: insufficient fee, rejecting replacement d05cdb24407169b39abfddd03ae9bef33a1eb49a7f59db4a39c19688a5af99b1, less fees than conflicting txs; 0.00003562 < 0.00009786`

I would like to know how to calculate the minimum replacement fee (0.00009786)，

the getmempoolinfo：`{"result":{"loaded":true,"size":42800"bytes":80705990,"usage":253822900,"total_fee":6.57420956,"maxmempool":300000000,"mempoolminfee":0.00002600,"minrelaytxfee":0.00001000,"incrementalrelayfee":0.00001000,"unbroadcastcount":0,"fullrbf":false},"error":null,"id":"curltest"}`

Answer (score 0):

> The replacement transaction must pay for its own bandwidth in addition
> to the amount paid by the original transactions at or above the rate
> set by the node's minimum relay fee setting. For example, if the
> minimum relay fee is 1 satoshi/byte and the replacement transaction is
> 500 bytes total, then the replacement must pay a fee at least 500
> satoshis higher than the sum of the originals.

So to calculate the minimum replacement fee for your tx, calculate the `minrelaytxfee` from your mempoolinfo times the size of your replacement tx.